# Remove gradient from push segue

Tags: ios, swift

While going through Pinterests signup process, I noticed they had really nice and smooth transitions because it seems as if they have removed the gradient (see below). If you look at the sample I have created there is a gradient line where the page ends and the new one slides over. Is there a way to get rid of this to mimic the gradient-less transition Pinterest has created?

[image]

[image]

Comment: I think you can manage this by adding a size screen view at the right of your current view and animate everything to the left. So you use only one ViewController and no segue.

Comment: create an object conforming to the <UIViewControllerAnimatedTransitioning> protocol. This approach gives you the greatest flexibility and nicer end results. For example, you could animate the segue button left and animate the presented view controller independanty.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `UIPageViewController` with scroll transition style or create custom transitions for your `UINavigationController`